# django-wysiwyg-redactor doesn't apply any settings

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a trouble with [django-wysiwyg-redactor](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-wysiwyg-redactor/) working on Django 1.8.
I need to make toolbar fixed at admin site but RedactorField doesn't apply any setting that I try to use. Admin site uses django-grappelli 2.7.3.

I tried all matters that are explained in the docs, but I haven't changes at my Admin site even on the simpliest setting - 'maxWidth':'100px':

1) Write settings at settings.py as explained here [enter link description here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-wysiwyg-redactor/)

```
REDACTOR_OPTIONS = {'maxWidth': '100px'}
```

2) Use RedactorField at models.py in model definition (also as at the docs example):

```
announce = RedactorField(redactor_options={'maxWidth': '150px'})
```

(I tried also with redactor_settings as it is in the [source code](https://github.com/mazelife/django-redactor/blob/master/redactor/widgets.py#L33) instead of redactor_options but it throws and error '*init*() got an unexpected keyword argument 'redactor_settings'')

3) Use RedactorEditor at my forms.py as widget:

```
# this raises '_init_() got unexpected word' exception because of redactor_settings
announce = forms.CharField(widget=RedactorEditor(redactor_settings={'maxWidth': '100px'}))
```

(I tried also with redactor_settings as it is in the [source code](https://github.com/mazelife/django-redactor/blob/master/redactor/widgets.py#L33) instead of redactor_options but it throws and error '*init*() got an unexpected keyword argument 'redactor_settings'')

But any of them doesn't work. I will appreciate any help! I there is not enough info, I can show more source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!
The problem was that I used incorrect format of settings for my Redactor in settings.py file. This is the right (for fixed toolbar as I wanted):

```
REDACTOR_OPTIONS = {
  'lang': 'en',
  'toolbarFixedTopOffset': 70,
}
```